# cor command failing to create correlation table in R

Tags: r, correlation

I'm trying to create a correlation table with all the variables in this subset of the data. I have tried using this command:

```
cor(Correlation_Data_Subset)
```

But all it keeps spitting out NA's or 1's. The correlations don't look like they're strings, and

Below is my data

```
structure(list(enjoy = c(4, 1, 3.5, 4.25, 3.25, 3.5), RELATIONSHIP = c(4.33333349227905, 
1, 4.33333349227905, 3.66666674613953, 3.5, 3.66666674613953), 
    anxiety = c(3, 3.40000009536743, 2.20000004768372, 1.25, 
    2, 1.25), BEH_SIM = c(3, 1, 3.75, 2.75, 2.5, 1.75), sptconf = c(3.33333325386047, 
    1.5, 4, 4.83333349227905, 4, 3.66666674613953), NEG_EFFICACY = c(4, 
    1.16666662693024, 3.66666674613953, 4.83333349227905, 4.16666650772095, 
    4.5), spteffort = c(3.16666674613953, 3.5, 4.16666650772095, 
    3.16666674613953, 3.16666674613953, 3.5), SPTEFFORT_OTHER = c(3.16666674613953, 
    3.5, 3.5, 3.16666674613953, 3, 3.33333325386047), SIM_VALUES = c(3.75, 
    1, 3.75, 3.75, 1.5, 2.25), COOP_MOTIV = c(2.33333325386047, 
    3, 2.66666674613953, 5, 2.5, 2.66666674613953), TotalRangerComm = c(258.333343505859, 
    233.33332824707, 291.666656494141, 258.333343505859, 175, 
    166.66667175293)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `cor(df)` works fine for me though for above data.

Comment: Ugh really? Thanks much, I'll try it again. :)

Comment: Maybe you have missing values farther down in the data? Try `cor(df, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")`, and see `?cor` for details and other options.

Comment: Nope still get a bunch of NA's and a couple 1's. I'll try that Gregor!

Comment: success! Thanks Gregor and Ronak!! You are heroes.